# Jacobian in Change of Variables

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let us consider an integral $\int \mathrm{d} ^ 4 k _ {2} \int \mathrm{d} ^ 4 k _ {1} \, f (k _ {1}, k _ {2})$, where $k _ {1}$ and $k _ {2}$ are four-dimensional vectors in Euclidean space. We want to make a change of variables such that $\mathrm{d} ^ 4 k _ {1} \, \mathrm{d} ^ 4 k _ {2} = J \, \mathrm{d} ^ 4 k _ {3} \, \mathrm{d} ^ 4 k _ {4}$, where $J$ is the Jacobian determinant. We have that $k _ {3}$ and $k _ {4}$ are also four-dimensional vectors in Euclidean space.

If $k _ {1} = a k _ {3} +b k _ {4}$ and $k _ {2} = c k _ {3} + d k _ {4}$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are real coefficients, what is $J$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$?